# leak memory when load image from document folder

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I have two images. 
the one is saved at bundle

```
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",_path,[contents objectAtIndex:0]];
```

the other is saved at document folder

```
NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *contents = [filemanager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:_path error:nil];
   NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",_path,[contents objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Load image to UIImageView

```
_avatar = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

if i load image from bundle , the use memory increase to 2Mb
if i load image from document, the use memory increase to 40mb
the size of both images is 2448x3264

do have error in here.

Answer (score 0):

Saving to or retrieving the information from the disk is always costly(memory) and time consuming when compared to retrieving from the bundle. which means if you load the image from the documents directory the total image size will get added to your application size. This is the reason for the memory increase up to 40 mb as compared to loading image from the bundle.

Actually it is not a memory leak at all and you don't have to worry about this.